# Calculating correlation between variables x and y in data frame data for each category of a factor

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function that would give me correlation between variables x (age) and y (hours of watching tv) in a data frame for each category of a factor (in this case "sex")

```
##The function
partcorr <- function(data, x, y) {
  corrs <- list()
  for(i in levels(data[,cat])) {
    corrs[i] <- round(cor(data[data[,cat] == i, x], data[data[,cat] == i, y], method = "pearson"), digits = 2)
  }
  return(corrs)
}

##Function
partcorr(tv_viewing, "age", "views", "sex")
```

The error I get: Error in partcorr(tv_viewing, "age", "views", "sex") :
unused argument ("sex")

Can anybody point me towards the right direction? Thank youu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't post the data so I made some up, it's easy enough to get all the levels with a loop, but I've provided the function below as well. It takes a `data.frame` as an argument as well as the level of `gender`, which should be a string.

```
n <- 100
age <- rpois(n, 10)
tv <- rnorm(n, 100)
gender <- as.factor(sample(c(1,2,3), n, replace = TRUE))
df <- data.frame(age, tv, gender)
head(df)
# age        tv gender
# 1  14  98.37402      1
# 2   7 100.78864      2
# 3   7  99.88344      3
# 4  11  99.61374      2
# 5  14  99.47069      2
# 6   5 101.77038      3
gender_levels <- levels(df$gender)

out <- list()
for ( i in seq_along(gender_levels)) {
 out[[i]]<-   cor(df[df$gender == i,]$tv,df[df$gender == i,]$age )
}
out
# [[1]]
# [1] -0.1274395
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] -0.3406629
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] -0.4413302

cor_by_gender <- function(df, gender_type) {
                                           return(cor(df[df$gender == gender_type,]$tv,df[df$gender == gender_type,]$age ))
}

cor_by_gender(df, "1")
# [1] -0.1274395
```

Comment: thank you for this!!! The solution you've provided works perfectly. 

The only thing that I'm wondering is why is it not necessary to specify the type of correlation anymore and the code still works?

Btw can I ask a question? I'm new to stack overflow, can you advise me on how to include data in a question in the best way?

Comment: So, if this suitably answers your question remember to accept the response. Often people use df <- dput() and with a minor edit, which allows anyone to get your data in a nice format.  The function works without specifying the type because the default in cor() is "pearson", you can see all the options in ??cor, they are "pearson", "kendall", and "spearman." So, if you want one of the others you can just add that argument.

Comment: Thank you again for answering my rookie question:). I just love how helpful the community among r is, it makes the learning process much more fun. Hope you're having a great day!